# Color numpy array based on two condition (x and y axis)

Tags: python, numpy, colors, scatter-plot

I have to numpy arrays ,x and y , and I want to create scatter plot and to color the points based on the x **and** y axes values, so for example, all the points that thar x value is between 0.1-0.2 **and** their y value is between 0.4-0.6 will get the color red.
I have tried to do it the following way:

```
#generate points
num = 1000
x= np.random.rand(1,100)
y= np.random.rand(1,100)

plt.scatter(x, y, s=5, linewidth=0)
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
#try to color the points based on condition:
col=[(np.where((x<0.2,'r')&(y<0.4,'r','b')))]
plt.scatter(x, y,c=col, s=5, linewidth=0)
plt.show()

>>>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'tuple' and 'tuple'
```

i'm not sure that this is the best way to do that .
My end goal is to color values based on the defined x and y conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use bitwise and operations to filter out the needed points-

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

num = 1000
x = np.random.rand(1, 100)
y = np.random.rand(1, 100)

plt.scatter(x, y, s=5, linewidth=0)
mask = np.bitwise_and(np.bitwise_and(x < 0.2, x > 0.1), np.bitwise_and(y < 0.6, y > 0.4))
plt.scatter(x[mask], y[mask], c='r', s=5, linewidth=0)
plt.show()
```

[image]